How many of the four Knaves were telling the truth?
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

The following conversation took place:
Knave of Hearts: “I stole the tarts.”
Knave of Clubs: “The Knave of Hearts is lying.”
Knave of Diamonds: “The Knave of Clubs is lying.”
Knave of Spades: “The Knave of Diamonds is lying.”
How many of the four Knaves were telling the truth?
Clarification 1: Often in puzzles with knaves, the knaves are all liars. But in this puzzle the knaves aren’t necessarily liars.
Clarification 2: Each knave knows which of the other knaves are lying and which are telling the truth.

Attribution: UK Junior Mathematical Challenge 2015

I would be inclined to stick with the knaves always lie, knights always tell the truth terminology. The puzzle can trivially be re-phrased to fit that.

@Arkku When I post a puzzle that was created by someone else, I try to use as much of the original text as possible.

It is

 2

Since

There are only two possibilities:
 Knave 1 is true and so the rest is FTF or Knave 1 is false and the rest is TFT.

